# JOIN two tables return values, but when i use LEFT JOIN, it'll return syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I tried to `LEFT JOIN` my query, but it returned error like this

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your `MariaDB` server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> ```
> WHERE `data_binatang`.`id_binatang` = `data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`id_binatang`'
> ```
>
> at line 1

but when i wrote only JOIN, it returned the json value

here's my code:

```
  <?php
    include "../mainmenu/koneksi.php";

    $rows = array();

    $query = "SELECT `data_binatang`.`nama_binatang`, (SELECT min(`data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`tanggal_vaksin`) FROM `data_waktu_vaksinasi` WHERE `data_binatang`.`id_binatang` = `data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`id_binatang`) AS tanggal_awal FROM `data_binatang` JOIN `data_waktu_vaksinasi` WHERE `data_binatang`.`id_binatang` = `data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`id_binatang`";

    $query = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$query);

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) 
    {   
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;

    }   


    echo '{"data_vaksinasi_menu":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `where` to `on` after join like this

```
JOIN `data_waktu_vaksinasi` on `data_binatang`.`id_binatang` = `data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`id_binatang`";
```

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL JOIN you should specify the `JOIN` condition using `ON` instead of in the `WHERE` clause.

MySQL allows you to skip the `ON` condition when doing a `JOIN`, however, it does not allow you to skip `ON` when doing a `LEFT JOIN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT `data_binatang`.`nama_binatang`,
       (SELECT min(`data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`tanggal_vaksin`)
          FROM `data_waktu_vaksinasi`
         WHERE `data_binatang`.`id_binatang` = `data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`id_binatang`) AS tanggal_awal 
  FROM `data_binatang`
  LEFT JOIN `data_waktu_vaksinasi`
    ON `data_binatang`.`id_binatang` = `data_waktu_vaksinasi`.`id_binatang`
```